# How I can add input type to attribute in Woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How I can add input type to attribute. For example I want to add option to input custom size for product. Maybe I add image and hope this will be helpful.Thank your for help!!
http://s14.postimg.org/cl6an48k1/Ughjgntitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Advanced Custom Fields` Plugin?

You're able to add images, textboxes, inputs and a great deal more by attaching them to the Products post type.

Their documentation is fantastic – worth a look if you're going to customise products

http://advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: I don't try to use this plugin, but do you think it'll be integrated with variable product in woo commerce?

Comment: Yes you can, and i think this'll help you: http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/

Comment: Andrew may you know but I think it'll be easy to change only type of attribute to input?. Thank you for help)